# Highlighting substring in text property of JavaFX 2.0 Cells

Tags: java, javafx-2

Is it possible to highlight a substring inside of a TableView Cell in JavaFX 2 by giving the substring another color for example? If yes, how is this achievable?

Glad for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution for Java7.  Use a [cell factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory%28javafx.util.Callback%29) for your cell.  From the factory return a [TextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html).  Set the TextField to [not editable](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setEditable%28boolean%29).  Use the TextField's methods to [select the text](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#selectPositionCaret%28int%29) you want to highlight (might need a [Platform.runLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method to do that and the field might need to be focused to allow to select the text).  Once the selection is complete (and really displayed), [Disable mouse input](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setMouseTransparent%28boolean%29) and [focus traversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setFocusTraversable%28boolean%29) on the TextField so that the user can't change the selection maybe also in a Platform.runLater.

For Java8, you can do the similar thing, but instead of a TextField, use a [TextFlow](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) and style the subtext in the text flow using css or Java APIs.

If you just want to highlight all of the text in the cell, rather than some portion of it, then you can just use a standard [Label](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html) plus css styling.  Another solution for partial text highlighting is to use a FlowPane with multiple labels inside and different styling for each.

Comment: i like your last suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways for highlighting the substring of tableview cell. I used `HBox` and `label` and it looks good.

Here is my code:

```
public Callback<TableColumn<Address, String>, TableCell<Address, String>> getCellFactory() {
        return new Callback<TableColumn<Address, String>, TableCell<Address, String>>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell<Address, String> call( final TableColumn<Address, String> param ) {
                final TableCell<Address, String> cell = new TableCell<Address, String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem( final String value, final boolean empty ) {
                        setGraphic( null );
                        if( null != getTableRow() && !empty ) {
                            final HBox hbox = new HBox();
                            hbox.setAlignment( Pos.CENTER_LEFT );
                            hbox.getChildren().clear();
                            if( null == value ) {
                                return;
                            }

                        final int index = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(str);

                        if( -1 == index ) {
                            //no match
                            hbox.getChildren().add( new Label( value ) );
                        } else {
                            //part of string before match
                            hbox.getChildren().add( new Label( value.substring( 0, index ) ) );
                            //matched part
                            final Label label = new Label( value.substring( index, index + str.length() ) );
                            label.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: #FFFFBF;-fx-text-fill: #FF0000;" );
                            hbox.getChildren().add( label );
                            //part of string after match
                            final int lastPartIndex = index + str.length();
                            if( lastPartIndex < value.length() ) {
                                hbox.getChildren().add( new Label( value.substring( lastPartIndex ) ) );
                            }
                        }
                        setGraphic( hbox );
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    };
}
```